# How to associate app link in android library?

Tags: android, sdk, deep-linking, applinks, android-app-links

I have created android library which uses app-link to redirect the users back to application and open the specific activity. It works all good but I have below concerns which I am not able to understand.

1. I am using the Android studio app link assistant to generate "Digital Asset Links file" and associate the website. Will this approach work in production(google play store) as well, when someone tries to integrate my library? Since the singing key of the parent app and my library is different.
2. Also should I create new domain for this purpose? My current domain is used to host frontend angular project. I am not sure adding the .well-known to this project assets/root would be a good idea.

Let me know what you think or the best practices regarding android app linking?

Edit1:
The android library will be used by external clients.

Comment: Who is using this library? Question 1 implies that it is somebody other than you. Question 2 implies that it is only you.

Comment: @CommonsWare: The library will be used by external clients

Comment: Adding more to Question 2: I wanted to check if is it a good idea to use the domain where my website is hosted or should I create a sub domain specifically for app link stuffs. The reason why I am asking this because, the .well-known folder has to be added in the root folder of the project. Not sure if that will affect my actual website

Comment: "The library will be used by external clients" -- then what app links are you expecting them to use? Are you expecting them to use app links tied to their domain? Or are you expecting them to use app links tied to your domain?

Comment: @CommonsWare: The app links will be only consumed by the android library itself, so it will be tied up to my domain. 
So my main question is point 1, the sha256_cert_fingerprints created via the android studio assistant for the library (I created) work with application (for external clients) signed by google play console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The app links will be only consumed by the android library itself, so it will be tied up to my domain

I suspect that is impractical.

> Since the singing key of the parent app and my library is different.

Libraries are not signed, at least in any fashion that impacts app links.

> Will this approach work in production(google play store) as well, when someone tries to integrate my library?

You will need to require that consumers of your library to provide the details of *their* apps to put in `assetlinks.json` for *your* domain. And, you will need to take those details and add them to `assetlinks.json` yourself. Some developers will not be interested in being involved in this or will otherwise ignore this step.

Also, if 2+ apps using your library are installed on a particular device, which app will wind up handling the app link is indeterminate.

Hence, I suspect that what you are trying to do is impractical.

> Also should I create new domain for this purpose?

You need to use a domain that has a Web site that supports each of your app links. If somebody gets an app link and does not have a compatible app installed, the link needs to work in a Web browser or similar Web client. Whether that Web site is the one that has your existing project or is a separate site is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think like you mentioned, the client will not be interested in sharing the assetlinks.json. I am not sure if there is any other way to deeplink into the library directly. Since we need to add the logic(host/scheme) to handle the intent in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: If I just use below deeplink intent inside the android library and publish it to Maven central. Will this work when external clients tries to integrate into their application?
Thanks!


```
 <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:host="test"
                    android:scheme="library" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: @Jayj: If `test` is a placeholder for your domain name, then I think that I covered this in my answer. Your `assetlinks.json` file will need to contain details of every possible app that will be launched by those app links.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear earlier. The clients probably won't like assetslinks.json. what if I use just the deeplink instead of the app links. The intent code I added above, will that work with android Library?

Comment: All the external clients will integrate the Android library. The library will have one of the activity with above test intent. If the link is launched from browser (library://test), will it resume clients application pointing to that specific library activity?

Comment: @Jayj: "what if I use just the deeplink instead of the app links" -- AFAIK, that means the app will not launch automatically when the user clicks on the link. The user will be presented with a chooser instead, allowing the choice of all installed apps that can handle the link. That includes all apps that integrate your library, any Web browsers, and possibly other apps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That helps me. There will be only one app that will integrate my library at any given time. And if I create unique deep link, that should narrow down to one option for the user to choose from. Thanks again!