# Android - associating app link to an Android library

Tags: android, kotlin, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I realize that a similar question was asked here [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77237145/how-to-associate-app-link-in-android-library), but I want to rephrase it as well as confirming there is no other option than what I am about to list below.

I have developed an Android library that has UI components/screens that will be consumed by my own app as well as multiple other client apps. There is a flow within my library that will launch a browser to complete some tasks and jump back to the app via deeplink.

So far, I've succeeded in generating and hosting the *Digital Asset Links* file (`assertlinks.json`) and associating it with my domain. Since I have the `sha256_cert_fingerprints` of my sample app within that file, my sample application works and the link gets verified automatically when the app is installed on a device.

But how would this work for the consumer apps of my library? Their app will have a different `sha256_cert_fingerprints` than mine. Do each consumer have to send me their app's fingerprint and I have to manually add them to the *Digital Asset Links* file?

All I'm trying to do is be able to launch a browser and deeplink back into my library's screen from a consumer app. If there is a better approach, please let me know.

Comment: If there are two or more apps installed that each have your library, what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I've used the manifest placeholders to create unique path for each apps. I've verified this works by having two sample apps on my device.

Answer (score 0):

> Do each consumer have to send me their app's fingerprint and I have to manually add them to the Digital Asset Links file?

Yes. Specifically, it needs to be the fingerprint(s) of the apps as seen by the OS. So, in the case of a Google Play-distributed app signed via Google Play Signing, it would be Google's certificate's fingerprint, not the certificate used for uploading.

I have "fingerprint(s)" because there may be multiple build variants with distinct application IDs and distinct fingerprints that have to be taken into account.